# sem_wait not blocking the program after a signal handler function executes

Tags: c, semaphore, signal-handling

I have a program that is similar to the following code schema:

```
void foo () {
    write(1, "Test\n", strlen("Testt"));

    signal(SIGALRM, foo);
    alarm(120);
}

int main() {

    //...

    int n = fork();

    switch(n) {

        case 0: //child process

            signal(SIGALRM, foo);

            while (1) {
                SEM_wait(&sinc);

                //...
                write(1, "Test 2\n", strlen("Test 2\n"));
                //...

                if (i == 0) { //if it's the first iteration
                    alarm(5);
                    i++;
                }
            }
        break;

        //...
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm reprogramming `SIGALRM` so it executes function `foo()` when an `alarm(x)` is "sent". Also note that `sinc` semaphore is a synchronization semaphore that has been constructed an initialized to 0.

The issue comes when I "send" a `sem_signal(&sinc)` to the loop in the child process so it unblocks and executes the code inside the `while` loop. In the first iteration, an `alarm(5)` will execute function `foo` and then the child process is supposed to block again with `sem_wait(&sinc)`, but instead, after the 5 seconds till the `SIGALRM` is sent, `foo` executes and unblocks the process (like if it sent a `sem_signal(&sinc)`... I did some testing and even if `foo` is an empty function, this happens. This issue does not happen if I deleted `signal(SIGALRM, foo)` right before the `while` loop in the child process but I need to use that...

What's wrong?

Comment: Is your issue that `SEM_wait()` returns after the signal handler, instead of continuing to wait?  This is documented behavior.  You should see it return `-1` and set `errno` to `EINTR`, which is how you know the semaphore wasn't decremented.  If you want it to continue waiting, set up the signal handler using `sigaction()` and the `SA_RESTART` flag.

Comment: Do you have a link or web name where I can read this documentation?

Comment: The [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_wait.3.html) is the primary documentation for any Linux system call.  "If the
       semaphore currently has the value zero, then the call blocks
       until either it becomes possible to perform the decrement (i.e.,
       the semaphore value rises above zero), **or a signal handler
       interrupts the call.**"  See also the reference to [`signal(7)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) further down, which explains system call restarting.

Comment: If you are using linux, note that `sem_wait()` will *always* be interrupted by a signal regardless of if the handler was registered with `SA_RESTART` or not.

Comment: @Shawn: The `signal(7)` man page says that was true prior to Linux 2.6.22, but since then `SA_RESTART` is respected.  I tested this and can confirm.

Comment: @NateEldredge That's not what the `sem_wait` manpage on my system says. And it explains what OP is seeing since glibc `signal()` installs restartable handlers.

Comment: I think many Linux man pages write things like "until interrupted by a signal" without explicitly saying "unless `SA_RESTART`", but it's supposed to be implied.  The `read(2)` man page is similar and everyone knows that `SA_RESTART` does the right thing there.

Comment: @NateEldrege See the notes section of https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man3/sem_wait.3.html It explicitly mentions `SA_RESTART`.

Comment: Hang on, I've been assuming Linux, but OP didn't actually say that.  What operating system is this for?  Signal semantics vary.

Comment: @Shawn: Anyway, in my tests on Linux, installing a signal handler with plain `signal()` results in `sem_wait` *not* being interrupted, since as you say `SA_RESTART` is the default with glibc.  So either OP has a different system, or something else is going on.

Comment: @Shawn: That note's no longer present as of Ubuntu 20.04: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man3/sem_wait.3.html.  So I guess there was a change in between.  Maybe OP is using an older version like you are.